# Suppress zero values in Power BI Line graph

Tags: data-visualization, powerbi, dax

I am attempting to make a graph that has one column with a full month of data (black bars), and one column that fills up as the days of the month progress (green bars). I would also like to track the percentage of the forecast achieved each day as a line graph (red line) on the secondary axis.

The problem I am having is that it does not appear that one can exclude values that are zero. So in the graph I would like to have the red line disappear once the values become zero so that there isn't a massive drop of like in the image shown.

[image: Graph showing the percentage drop of]

Comment: Can you add a filter where difference<>0?

Comment: Create a calculated column where the values are blank() when the original column is zero.

Comment: I used the below function with BLANK() incorporated:

= Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows1", "Custom", each if [#"%difference"] = 0 then BLANK() else [#"%difference"])

The error I am receiving now is the saying that the name BLANK() is not recognised.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem I inserted a blank spot if the condition is true. That is a "" after the 'then' statement to force a NULL. After this I changed the data type to percentage. 
The code is shown below and the resulting graph is shown afterwards.

= Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows1", "AdjDiff", each if [#"%difference"] = 0 then "" else if [#"%difference"] <> 0 then [#"%difference"] else null)

[image: Corrected Percentage Difference Line Graph]

Comment: Good job Hein, nice solution.